# Spark Streaming contain text

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to find text to in my streaming text.

```
val myTwitter = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None,)
val incoming = myTwitter.map(status => status.getText())
```

I want to analyze incoming text based on a key.If it is exist,i will take if not don't care.How can i do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a example from the input and output you expect

Comment: My input file is a twit.like as '@thoram my twitter is active'. and i want to anlyze based key as 'twitter'.If it has 'twitter' i will take this twit.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
val myTwitter = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None,)
val incoming = myTwitter.filter(status => status.getText().contains("twitter"))
```

work?

Comment: yes it worked :) but 
    val tweetsA = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, Array("searchWord1"))


    val tweets_mystring = tweetsA.filter(_.getText.contains("searchWord2")).map(ttext => ttext.getText)
    tweets_mystring.map(??????).saveToCassandra("Tutorial", "mytable")


    ssc.start() **I want to write save to cassandra but how can i do ?